# concatenating multiple file contents

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have 2 folders containing files:

FolderA:

file_1M1.txt, file_1M2.txt, file_1M3.txt.........

FolderB:

file_2M17.txt, file_1M18.txt, file_1M19.txt........

I prepared lists of files on txt files:

FileA.txt contains:

```
file_1M1.txt
file_1M2.txt
file_1M3.txt
```

FileB.txt contains:

```
file_2M17.txt
file_1M18.txt
file_1M19.txt
```

FileC.txt contains:

```
iuk
umn
ilu
```

I wanted to concatenate the files in folders A and B with the content of fileC.txt appended to each file as follows:

```
cat file_1M1.txt file_2M17.txt > F1_F2_iuk.txt
file_1M2.txt file_2M18.txt > F1_F2_umn
```

I wrote the following code for implementing the task:

```
cat FileA.txt, FileB.txt, FileC.txt | while read i, j, k;
do
    cat file-path-to-folderA/${i} file-path-to-folderB/${j} > file-path-to-output-folder/F1_F2_${k}.txt
end
```

Running the above code in linux generated errors: "files not found and also i not a good variable"

Please help!

Comment: You changed all the `#` characters to `M`? Does this question accurately reflect the filenames you're using?

Comment: why is this tagged python?

Comment: I can't imagine that either `bash` or `cat` has an error message that says "files not found and also i not a good variable". Post the actual error messages.

Comment: Anyway, just doing the `cat FileA.txt, FileB.txt, FileC.txt` part itself, without all the rest of it, will immediately show you the problem: `cat: FileA.txt,: No such file or directory`. Commas are a perfectly valid character in filenames, so it's looking for a file named `"FileA.txt,"`, because that's what you asked for, and not finding it, because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unnecessary commas, and incorrect use of `cat`.  Change it to:

```
paste FileA.txt FileB.txt FileC.txt | while read i j k; do ...
```

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks for your help William. Your suggested modification worked fine.